# Innodb tables not showing

Tags: mysql, innodb, sql

If I run query `show table` in mysql console, the innodb tables will be listed. But when I tried a query like `select * from tablename`, it says table does not exist.

How can I fix this issue and make the table and its data work again?

Comment: We need you to run `SHOW ENGINES;` and look for the `InnoDB` row. What is the value for the `Support` column ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `SHOW TABLES` reads content of database directory and shows tables when it finds respective frm file.

When you select from the table it reports error because InnoDB dictionary doesn't have that table.

This is inconstsency between the dictionary and set of available .frm files